# VBA Drag and Drop behaviour in Outlook UserForm without 'MS Windows Common Controls 6.0' reference

Tags: vba, outlook, drag-and-drop, treeview, userform

I have built a userform with drag and drop functionality in using a TreeView sand OLEDragDrop functionality. Unfortunately some of my colleagues don't have MS Windows Common Controls (SP6). I have narrowed the problem down to not having a declaration of MSComct1Lib.DataObject.

I can't use the OLEDragDrop event without having that object type in the parameters declaration.

Is there a work around to make VBA think that the object type exists similar to the `Declare Function...Alias...As...` syntax? Or maybe some other way of getting drag and drop functionality without that library?

My code snippet is below and works with most users:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_OLEDragDrop(data As MSComctlLib.DataObject, Effect As Long, Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, x As Single, y As Single)
    Dim mAttachmentsCurrentSize As Long, numberOfDragAndDropFiles As Long
    Dim index As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    mAttachmentsCurrentSize = UBound(mAttachments)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    numberOfDragAndDropFiles = data.Files.count

    If mAttachmentsCurrentSize = 0 Then mAttachments = Array()
    ReDim Preserve mAttachments(1 To mAttachmentsCurrentSize + numberOfDragAndDropFiles)
    For index = 1 To numberOfDragAndDropFiles
        LabelFileList.caption = LabelFileList.caption & vbNewLine & data.Files(index)
        mAttachments(index + mAttachmentsCurrentSize) = data.Files(index)
    Next index
 End Sub
```